# Private views like button or textView

Tags: java, android

I wonder why people recommend implement views(example buttons or textviews) in Android as `private`
It is good practive ? Someone can explain why ?  I meet  programmers in my life who  themselves why do that. They just say "everybody do that".

Comment: what do you mean? Post a sample of code. 
Probably you are talking about private fields to access views inside of your class

Comment: button is not a field

Comment: You may have better luck if you edit your question and explain, in detail and with examples, what "implement views... as private" means.

Comment: Any class level variable that you don't need to access from other classes should be private.  Even then they should usually be private and accessed via getters and setters if necessary.  This is basic data encapsulation.  If you don't understand this, you really need to study object oriented programming.

Comment: @philips, actually any variable (doesn't matter view or not), inside of your class is a field. Something you want to share should be declared with `public` modificator, othervise you better use `private` to be strict to Incapsulation principle of OOP.

Comment: @philips, please, provide some example of the code so we could provide exact answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members of a class can have different levels of access: private, protected, public. Private just in class, protected in class and subclasses, public all classes, more detail at:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

It is good to use private where possible, as public variables can cause unexpected results when shared between classes. For example, a variable being used in a class declared public and then used in another class thinking it is resstricted to that class.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head when you said, "It is good to use private where possible, (sic) as public variable can cause unexpected results when shared between classes."

Comment: it's everything about Incapsulation, you use different access level - you protect your class of changes of the base functionality. Only something useful for other classes should be public, your class needs to be like "black box" little bit